# ASP.NET WebService test form

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

Is it possible to configure default ASP.NET WebService test form to support JSON?
I mean the test form that built in in .NET framework...

Currently I have a WebService that decorated with `[ScriptService]`, but when I testing it using built in test form page, it returns XML...I assume, this happens because test page sends Content-Type XML by default.

Thanks

**EDIT (Example)**:
I have class:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have ASP.NET WebService:

```
[ScriptService]
public class PersonService : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public Person GetDave()
  {
    Person dave = new Person();

    dave.FirstName = "Dave";
    dave.LastName = "Test";

    return dave;
  }
}
```

When I call this WebService from web page using jQuery AJAX, I receive JSON Person object `{"FirstName":"Dave","LastName":"Test"}` (not string) in JavaScript, but when I invoking this WebService from ASP.NET WebService Test Form (When I right click on ASMX file and use "Preview In Browser"),

[image]

It returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <FirstName>Dave</FirstName> 
  <LastName>Test</LastName> 
</Person>
```

What want, is when I invoke the service from test page, to see the same output:

```
{"FirstName":"Dave","LastName":"Test"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Some Description")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string FunctionName()
{           
    // Return JSON data
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string retJSON = js.Serialize(Object);
    return retJSON;
}
```

And also you need to add the reference.

**Update**

Here is the link which will explain about [extending an existing ASP.NET Web Service to support JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28310/Extending-an-existing-ASP-NET-Web-Service-to-suppo)

Hope that helps

Comment: But this will force to change current JS to parse received JSON string to object (in production code). I still want to return strong type from service and not JSON string.

Comment: I added an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found a solution...it still not complete solution, but this is the way to go :)

In `[Drive]:\[WindowsDir]\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[Version]\CONFIG` folder, exists the file named `DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx`. This file contains the whole code needed to automatically generate test page using WSDL. Now I can use this code to write my own test page  and make requests using jQuery and not using HTML form...then I can put in config file and this should work.

```
<webServices>
      <wsdlHelpGenerator href="WSTestPage.aspx"/>
</webServices>
```

Maybe somewhere exists more simple/ready way to do it, but I still not found it...

Answer (score 0):

Add following references first

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

use the below code in your method, for converting any data into JSON Data format in end

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(dr);
```

dr is array of DataRows from DataTable.Hope this will help You.

Comment: As a previous answer, it will force to change current JS to parse received JSON string to object (in production code). I still want to return strong type from service and not JSON string.

Comment: @AlexDn can you provide us code snippet that shows what you have done and what is your real problem.